# Converting a number to datetime sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the number 20080331.

I need to cast/convert this into a datetime so I can do a date comparison within the database. How will i go about converting this number. Using CONVERT(DATETIME, Value) does not seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(20110331 AS VARCHAR(8)), 112)
```

Comment: @JNK: sure, noticed that late.

Comment: Thanks I was missing the convert to string(varchar)

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast to a character type first;

```
select cast(cast(20080331 as varchar(8)) as datetime)

>>2008-03-31 00:00:00.000
```